# fixed positioned button on small screens

Tags: html, css, css-position

everyone. I'm trying to make a button with a fixed position. The problem is on small screens it's completely dissapears.

my css code

```css
.sound_button{
  background:  #FFD700 url("Images/background1.jpg") center ;



}
.sound_container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1180px;
  top: 520px;

}
```

My html code

```html
<div class="w3-container sound_container w3-mobile"">
    <button class="w3-button w3-circle w3-xxlarge sound_button"><i class="fa fa-music"></i></button>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your button is being positioned off the screen on smaller screens. A small screen might have a screen size of 1136 x 640 pixels (and smaller for other devices). So your current `top` and `left` properties would position it out of view for many small screens.

One solution is to use a media query to position the button at different positions on different sized screens. The snippet below will position the button at 100px (top and left) on small screens. And any screens above 900px in width will move the button to 1180px and 520px top and left.

```css
.sound_button {
  background: #FFD700 url("Images/background1.jpg") center;
}

.sound_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .sound_container {
    left: 1180px;
    top: 520px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container sound_container w3-mobile">
    <button class="w3-button w3-circle w3-xxlarge sound_button "><i class="fa fa-music ">Button</i></button>
</div>
```

If you want it to move proportional to the screen size, use percentages for `left` and `top`. The snippet below will position the button 50% from the left, 50% from the top.

```css
.sound_button {
  background: #FFD700 url("Images/background1.jpg") center;
}

.sound_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container sound_container w3-mobile">
    <button class="w3-button w3-circle w3-xxlarge sound_button "><i class="fa fa-music ">Button</i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: But i want it to move along when I make my browser windows smaller. Like here. Take a look at the right down corner. There is a mute button. and it moves when the browswer windows is resized. https://plarium.com/play/en/vikings/013_pastoral_g?plid=104162&pxl=doubleclick_dbm&placement=cr_90525502&publisherid=li_12573092&utm_expid=.Yj2stLTsRzSJBogIbXACsQ.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fs.yimg.com%2Frq%2Fdarla%2F2-9-20%2Fhtml%2Fr-sf.html

Comment: Use percentages - I've added another snippet as an example

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved my day!